# Intersecting ranges when using RangeMap

Tags: java, guava

I came across a problem like

You are maintaining a trading platform for a hedge fund. Traders in your hedge fund execute trading strategies throughout the day. 
For the sake of simplicity let's assume that each trading strategy makes `i` pounds/minute for as long as it's running. `i` can be negative. 
In the end of the day you have a log file that looks as follows:

- timestamp_start_1, timestamp_end_1, i_1
- timestamp_start_2, timestamp_end_2, i_2
- timestamp_start_3, timestamp_end_3, i_3

Each line represents when the strategy started executing, when it stopped, and the income produced as a rate.
Write some code to return the time during the day when the hedge fund was making the highest amount of money per minute.

Examples:

Input:

- (1, 13, 400)
- (10, 20, 100)

Result :

- (10,13) 500

Input:

- (12,14, 400)
- (10,20,100)

Result:

- (12,14) 500

Input:

- (10, 20, 400)
- (21,25,100)

Result:

- (10,20) 400

I have been trying to use guava RangeMap to solve it, but there is no apparent way to intersect the overlapping intervals.

For example:

```
private static void method(Record[] array){
    RangeMap<Integer, Integer> rangeMap = TreeRangeMap.create();
    for (Record record : array) {
        rangeMap.put(Range.closed(record.startTime, record.endTime), record.profitRate);
    }
    System.out.println(rangeMap);   
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Record[] array = {new Record(1,13,400), new Record(10,20,100)};
    method(array);
}
```

And the map looks like: 
[[1..10)=400, [10..20]=100]

Is there any way to override the overlap behavior or any other data structure that can be used to solve the problem?

Comment: One has to assume that the `RangeMap` is only applicable to **disjoint** ranges (at least, that's what the JavaDoc say). Ignoring this (or even worse: trying to "tweak" this by overriding certain methods by chance) may result in unspecified behavior.

Comment: You could collect all the range boundaries and sort them, then create adjacent ranges, and for each of those ranges, find all the records in the input that overlap, and sum the values of these overlapping records. Then find the range(s) which has (have) the max value.

Answer (score 3):

Use `RangeMap.subRangeMap(Range)` to identify all the existing range entries intersecting with some other particular range, which will allow you to filter out the intersections.

This might look something like:

```
void add(RangeMap<Integer, Integer> existing, Range<Integer> range, int add) {
  List<Map.Entry<Range<Integer>, Integer>> overlaps = new ArrayList<>(
      existing.subRangeMap(range).asMapOfRanges().entrySet());
  existing.put(range, add);
  for (Map.Entry<Range, Integer> overlap : overlaps) {
    existing.put(overlap.getKey(), overlap.getValue() + add);
  }
}
```

Comment: As mentioned in the comment: I think that the `RangeMap` is not suitable here in the first place, because the ranges may be overlapping.

Comment: @Marco13: You can work with that, though, by reducing the problem to intersections and a case where they don't overlap.  (For reference, I wrote RangeMap.)  For each range, select the sub-range of the `RangeMap` where there are already entries, and overwrite the values for that particular range with the sum.  This is totally doable.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understood this correctly (for a moment, I thought that this would imply adding **each** record with a new `rangeMap = rangeMap.subRangeMap(newRecordRange);` call, but that can hardly be right). A few lines of code to illustrate the strategy could be helpful. Otherwise, I just want to express my doubts whether there is any built-in functionality that makes this "easier" or "more elegant" than manually searching for all overlapping invervals.

Comment: @Marco13 added some code; it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: OK, this may be "handy" to make the code more compact. But if I'm not mistaken, then this will have `O(n*n)` (where `n` is the number of records) in contrast to the `O(n)` approach of manually keeping track of the active ranges while scanning over them (`O(n*logn)` for creating the set of relevant time points - as I said, there might be room for optimizations in this regard, if one knows that the ranges are "ordered" in any way...)

Comment: I suspect if you sorted the ranges, say by open position, first, then it'd be more or less equivalent?  In any event, this answers the original question of how to do this with RangeMap.

Comment: Not sure. Imagine 10 ranges, each starting with an offset of 1 second to the previous (and have a length of 100 or so). For each of them, you would have to go through the `overlaps`, which, for each new range, would be one overlap for each range that was added previously. This is `O(n)` for each range, and thus `O(n*n)`. (In the implementation of `subRangeMap`, there is likely an an `O(logn)`, so this shouldn't matter - although I haven't read the implementation yet). While the code is nice, simple and compact, I'm not sure whether the running time here may be an issue....

Comment: TreeRangeMap supports putCoalescing() that will merge ranges as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments: A `RangeMap` is probably not suitable for this, because the ranges of a `RangeMap` have to be disjoint.

One approach for solving this in general was mentioned in the comments: One could combine all the ranges, and *generate* all disjoint ranges from that. For example, given these ranges

```
  |------------|       :400
           |----------|:100
```

one could compute all sub-ranges that are implied by their intersections

```
  |--------|           :400
           |---|       :500
               |------|:100
```

Where the range in the middle would obviously be the solution in this case.

But in general, there are some imponderabilities in the problem statement. For example, it is not entirely clear whether multiple ranges may have *the same start time* and/or *the same end time*. Things that may be relevant for possible optimizations may be whether the records are "ordered" in any way.

But regardless of that, one generic approach could be as follows:

- Compute a mapping from all *start times* to the records that start there
- Compute a mapping from all *end times* to the records that end there
- Walk through all start- and end times (in order), keeping track of the accumulated profit rate for the current interval

(Yes, this **is** basically the generation of the disjoint sets from the comments. But it does not "construct" a data structure holding this information. It just uses this information to compute the maximum, on the fly).

An implementation could look like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

class Record
{
    int startTime;
    int endTime;
    int profitRate;

    public Record(int startTime, int endTime, int profitRate)
    {
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.endTime = endTime;
        this.profitRate = profitRate;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "(" + startTime + "..." + endTime + ", " + profitRate + ")";
    }

}

public class MaxRangeFinder
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        test01();
        test02();
    }

    private static void test01()
    {
        System.out.println("Test case 01:");
        Record[] records = {
            new Record(1,13,400), 
            new Record(10,20,100),
        };
        Record max = computeMax(Arrays.asList(records));
        printNicely(Arrays.asList(records), max);
    }

    private static void test02()
    {
        System.out.println("Test case 02:");
        Record[] records = {
            new Record(1,5,100), 
            new Record(2,6,200),
            new Record(3,4,50),
            new Record(3,4,25),
            new Record(5,8,200),
        };
        Record max = computeMax(Arrays.asList(records));
        printNicely(Arrays.asList(records), max);
    }


    private static Record computeMax(Collection<? extends Record> records)
    {
        // Create mappings from the start times to all records that start 
        // there, and from the end times to the records that end there 
        Map<Integer, List<Record>> recordsByStartTime =
            new LinkedHashMap<Integer, List<Record>>();
        for (Record record : records)
        {
            recordsByStartTime.computeIfAbsent(record.startTime,
                t -> new ArrayList<Record>()).add(record);
        }
        Map<Integer, List<Record>> recordsByEndTime =
            new LinkedHashMap<Integer, List<Record>>();
        for (Record record : records)
        {
            recordsByEndTime.computeIfAbsent(record.endTime,
                t -> new ArrayList<Record>()).add(record);
        }

        // Collect all times where a record starts or ends
        Set<Integer> eventTimes = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        eventTimes.addAll(recordsByStartTime.keySet());
        eventTimes.addAll(recordsByEndTime.keySet());

        // Walk over all events, keeping track of the 
        // starting and ending records
        int accumulatedProfitRate = 0;
        int maxAccumulatedProfitRate = -Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int maxAccumulatedProfitStartTime = 0;
        int maxAccumulatedProfitEndTime = 0;

        for (Integer eventTime : eventTimes)
        {
            int previousAccumulatedProfitRate = accumulatedProfitRate;

            // Add the profit rate of the starting records
            List<Record> startingRecords = Optional
                .ofNullable(recordsByStartTime.get(eventTime))
                .orElse(Collections.emptyList());
            for (Record startingRecord : startingRecords)
            {
                accumulatedProfitRate += startingRecord.profitRate;
            }

            // Subtract the profit rate of the ending records
            List<Record> endingRecords = Optional
                .ofNullable(recordsByEndTime.get(eventTime))
                .orElse(Collections.emptyList());
            for (Record endingRecord : endingRecords)
            {
                accumulatedProfitRate -= endingRecord.profitRate;
            }

            // Update the information about the maximum, if necessary
            if (accumulatedProfitRate > maxAccumulatedProfitRate)
            {
                maxAccumulatedProfitRate = accumulatedProfitRate;
                maxAccumulatedProfitStartTime = eventTime;
                maxAccumulatedProfitEndTime = eventTime;
            }
            if (previousAccumulatedProfitRate == maxAccumulatedProfitRate &&
                accumulatedProfitRate < previousAccumulatedProfitRate)
            {
                maxAccumulatedProfitEndTime = eventTime;
            }
        }

        return new Record(
            maxAccumulatedProfitStartTime, 
            maxAccumulatedProfitEndTime, 
            maxAccumulatedProfitRate);

    }



    private static void printNicely(
        Collection<? extends Record> records, 
        Record max)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int maxEndTime =  Collections.max(records, 
            (r0, r1) -> Integer.compare(r0.endTime, r1.endTime)).endTime;
        for (Record record : records)
        {
            sb.append("     ")
                .append(createString(record, maxEndTime))
                .append("\n");
        }
        sb.append("Max: ").append(createString(max, maxEndTime));
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }

    private static String createString(Record record, int maxEndTime)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < record.startTime)
        {
            sb.append(" ");
            i++;
        }
        sb.append("|");
        while (i < record.endTime)
        {
            sb.append("-");
            i++;
        }
        sb.append("|");
        while (i < maxEndTime)
        {
            sb.append(" ");
            i++;
        }
        sb.append(":").append(record.profitRate);
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

The output for the two test cases given in the code is

```
Test case 01:
      |------------|       :400
               |----------|:100
Max:           |---|       :500

Test case 02:
      |----|   :100
       |----|  :200
        |-|    :50
        |-|    :25
          |---|:200
Max:      |-|  :400
```